# How to extract value from splitted field in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Hi I want to know how could I extract and add a field from a splitted one:

```
mutate {    
    split => { "keys" => "#"} }
}
```

How could I apply a regex to get a value inside the multiple values obtained?
Inside each key I will have the needed value. Is it possible to extract this value with a regex and add them to a field?

Log line element:

```
#20171218|20171219|W|108|14579|QUA.AT|CG-TODOS|RO||1~2~2|9~7|N@14BF2F88A41849999EF9E61E5207AED61553#20171218|20171119|W|102|14979|QUA.AT|CG-TODOS|RO||1~2~2|9~7|N@14BF2F66A4184979AEF9E61E5202AED61553
```

I want to get the values splitted by "#" and put them in a field named "keys".
After that, I want to apply a regex to each value and get the value "QUA.ST" and add a field with that value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should add an example of the data you're working on and what is the intended result.

Comment: It could be doable with a ruby filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gork Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) before ES 5.0.
But if you are using es after 5.x and your logs are in fixed patterns, you can use [Dissect filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html).It's light and easier to write.